# How to call a simple http GET service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am learning Angular 2 and I am trying to call a simple HTTP Get request on page load for the JSON data I have and manipulate that JSON on page load. Can anyone tell me with some basic example how to do that? I am seeing most of the solutions on net from Beta version.

Answer (score 4):

Create a service like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'

export class MyService {
  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  private extractData(res) {

    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
      throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }

    // console.log(res.json());
    this.serviceData = (res.json());
    return this.serviceData || {};
  }

  loaddata(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.server_url) // define a variable server_url to assign the requested url
      .map(this.extractData);
  }
}
```

Now in your component's `ngOnInit` method get the values by calling this service method.

```
class MyComponent{
    constructor(public _myService: MyService)
    ngOnInit(){
      this._myService.loaddata().subscribe(data => {
      // do something with the data
    })

   }
}
```

Comment: Is it always important to use .subscribe after .map()?

Comment: @techiequestie, Yes, it is important. Since the API e.g. `loaddata` returns an Observable, we need to subscribe to it to actually perform the http request.

Answer (score 1):

To get the observable, you can follow the below example. The `getStories` method uses the **injected HTTP service** and returns an observable, which can be further used to get the response.

```
@Injectable()
export class StoriesService {

    constructor(private http:Http,private constService :ConstantsService) { }

    public getStories()
    {
        this.http
            .get(this.constService.apiBaseUrl + "Stories/Stories")
            .subscribe ((data: Response) => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

This is simple HTTP Get Service Example.